# Google Cloud Storage XML API fails to upload files larger than 50K

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I’m trying to upload files to Google Cloud Storage with Python and XML API. While it uploads OK some small files (e.g. `head -c 50K /dev/urandom > my_file`), but when I try to upload a bit larger files (e.g. `head -c 100K /dev/urandom > my_file`) I get the following response from the XML API:

```
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access denied.</Message>
  <Details>
    Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.create access to bucket [MY_DEFAULT_BUCKET].appspot.com.
  </Details>
</Error>
```

**How to upload large files to Google Cloud Storage with XML API?**

My code is the following:

```py
# main.py
import logging
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
from google.cloud import storage

app = Flask(__name__)

client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name()
bucket = client.bucket(bucket_name)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    acl = 'public-read'
    success_action_redirect = url_for('success', _external=True)
    conditions = [
            ['starts-with', '$key', ''],
            {'acl': acl},
            {'success_action_redirect': success_action_redirect}]
    policy = bucket.generate_upload_policy(conditions)
    return render_template('form.html',
            bucket_name=bucket_name,
            policy_items=policy.items(),
            acl=acl,
            success_action_redirect=success_action_redirect)

@app.route('/success')
def success():
    bucket_name = request.args['bucket']
    key = request.args['key']
    etag = request.args['etag']
    bucket = client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(key)
    return render_template('success.html',
            bucket_name=bucket_name,
            key=key,
            etag=etag,
            public_url=blob.public_url)

@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    logging.exception('An error occurred during a request.')
    return 'An internal error occurred.', 500
```

```html
<!-- form.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Upload a File</title>
<h1>Upload a File</h1>
<form action="http://{{bucket_name}}.storage.googleapis.com" method="post"
  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="key" value="my-test-key">
  <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="{{acl}}">
  <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect"
  value="{{success_action_redirect}}">
  <input name="file" type="file">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
  {% for key, value in policy_items %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{key}}" value="{{value}}">
  {% endfor %}
</form>
```

I also gave permissions to App Engine app default service account to upload to the default bucket:

```
$ gsutil acl ch -u [YOUR_PROJECT_ID]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:O gs://[YOUR_DEFAULT_BUCKET_NAME]
```

Comment: how do specify object name